# Running htaccess reverse proxy to access json-server data from internet

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess

In all the steps below I am working by remotely accessing hosting server. Hosting server is running apache. My hosting company is godaddy.

I have `db.json` with content:

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "title": "JSON SERVER",
      "author": "foo",
      "id": 1
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I started `json-server` by `json-server --watch db.json --port 1234`.

In `~/public_html/test-json-server/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://localhost:1234/posts/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:1234/posts/$1 [P,L]
```

Now, visiting `http://mywebsite.com/test-json-server/` gives empty data. But if I visit `http://mywebsite.com/test-json-server/1` it correctly returns

```
{
  "title": "JSON SERVER",
  "author": "foo",
  "id": 1
}
```

How do I fix `.htaccess` so that visiting `http://mywebsite.com/test-json-server/` displays all "posts" data?

I looked at the log while json-server is running and I got this:

```
GET /posts/index.html.var 404 7.552 ms - 2
GET /posts/index.html.var 404 2.918 ms - 2
GET /posts/1 304 4.065 ms - -
GET /posts/1 200 2.672 ms - 58
GET /posts/1 200 2.714 ms - 58
```

It seems I'm getting 404 error when I try to access `http://mywebsite.com/test-json-server/`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. My htaccess is:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://localhost:1234/posts/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:1234/posts/$1 [P,L]
```

Thanks a lot!